# Funny questions about Moebius Function

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, probabilistic-number-theory

I need to firstly claim that my research is not about number theory, however, I am pretty interested in it, especially funny questions in number theory, e.g. Kollatz Conjecture. Three years ago, I attended a lecture in which the lecturer discussed about entropy and natural numbers. Since then, I became very interested in randomness of Moebius function, I came up with three funny questions as the following:

(1) Given a finite $\{0, 1, -1\}$ sequence (e.g.$\{0,0,1,-1,0,-1,\cdots\,1\}$), can we find a consecutive natural number sequence such that values of Moebius function of this natural number sequence is the given $\{0, 1, -1\}$ sequence ? (existence)
If there exists such a natural number sequence, is it unique ? (uniqueness)

If we remove the restriction of consecutivity on natural number sequence, what about existence and uniqueness ?

(2) Given a finite $\{0, 1, -1\}$ $K$-sequence equipped with a spacing sequence (e.g. $\{n_{1},n_{2},\cdots,n_{K-1}\}$), can we find a natural number sequence such that values of Moebius function of this natural number sequence is the given $\{0, 1, -1\}$ sequence and this natural number sequence satisfies the given spacing sequence ?

(3) General Question: Is there some deterministic pattern or probabilistic properties for values of Moebius function of the whole natural numbers ?

Comment: I proposed these questions only out of **curiosity**!!!

Comment: Note that every fourth number has $\mu=0$.

Comment: Mobius function is completely deterministic, just like the sequence of primes is, but for purposes of heuristic it can be treated as a more or less random function. One interesting fact is that the summatory function of Mobius function, known as the Mertens function, satisfies the same bounds as a uniform random walk, $M(x)=O(x^{1/2+\varepsilon})$, iff the Riemann hypothesis holds.

Comment: It is trivial (by the pigeonhole principle) that there is a sequence of every finite length with entries from $\{0,1,-1\}$ that occurs as consecutive values of the Möbius function infinitely often. See also https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.05096 for state-of-the-art nontrivial results in the subject.

Comment: @Wojowu Thank you so much! I think I can propose a new hypothesis that Riemann hypothesis can appear everywhere in number theory. :)

Comment: @GHfromMO Thank you for your answer. I will check that paper later.

Comment: @cheng: It is a most natural thing that the Riemann Hypothesis is relevant for the Möbius function, since $\sum\mu(n)/n^s$ equals $1/\zeta(s)$.

Comment: @GHfromMO Yes. There are many formulas which link Riemann's $\zeta$ function with number theoretical functions such as Moebius function. What I feel surprised is there are so many equivalent versions of Riemann hypothesis. Maybe, from those formulas, it's a natural thing.

Comment: @cheng: Well, this is the power of complex analysis. For example, the poles of $1/\zeta(s)$ and $\zeta'(s)/\zeta(s)$ are the same as the zeros of $\zeta(s)$. If you are interested in the statistical behaviour of the Möbius function, then analytic number theory is your friend. See also this brand new preprint for a different, but related research direction: https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.12421

Comment: @Wojowu Yes. Mobius function is completely deterministic. However, it depends on prime decomposition of integer or identification of prime if the given integer is a prime. So, to some degree, Moebius function can characterize distribution of primes which is a central topic in number theory. I am interested in statistical behaviour of Moebius function, in particular, when the given integer is large enough, and prime decomposition is not tractable, if there exists an appropriate approximation to Moebius function $f : \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \{-1,0,1\}$, that will be great.

Comment: Cont: Actually, if we can find such $f$ satisfying some accuracy requirement theoretically or practically, we find an appropriate approximation to distribution of primes. As inspired in comments by @Wojowu, Moebius function can be regarded as a discrete-time stochastic process $X_{t} (t \in \mathbb{Z}), X_{t} \in \{-1,0,1\}$, an interesting analogue is $X_{t}$ can be regarded as stock price trending symbol, when $X_{t} = 1$, it means stock price increases at time $t$; similarly, when $X_{t} = -1$, stock price decreases; $X_{t} = 0$ means no change or ignorable change in stock price.

Comment: Cont: Based on observations in the past, we build a model to make predictions in the future. Back to reality, there is infinite number of integers, however, computer can only handle with finite number of integers. So, analogue makes sense here. Also, from fundamental theorem of primes, "density" of primes is low, corresponding to the fact stock price is almost always changing, $X_{t} = 0$ is rare.

Comment: @GHfromMO Thank you! I am interested in number theory, very mysterious! However, my complex analysis is ...tears.. My major is statistics, so I will try to dive deeper from statistical or probabilistical perspective. Interesting findings are  expected!